# jQuery .each problem

Tags: jquery, each

Brain squeeze and need help,

I have a table with 6 rows that are that can be hidden or visible depending on if a check box is checked. This .each routine works great with one small problem - when the last check box (val="5") is checked and you hit the refresh button the row 6 (with class="hide5") is hidden. This only occurs on the last check box - any other checkbox that is checked stays visible.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input:checkbox').each(
        function(rowIndex){
            if($('#view'+rowIndex).is(':checked') == true){
                $('.hide'+rowIndex).show();
            }
            else if($('#view'+rowIndex).is(':checked') == false){
                $('.hide'+rowIndex).hide();
            }
        }
    );
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {                             
        var row = this.value;
        $('.hide' + row).toggle();
    });
});
```

The HTML source for the 6<sup>th</sup> row is:

```
<tr class="hide5">
  <td width="175" align="center" style="padding:1px 0px 11px 0px"><br />
    <span>Total</span><br />
    <span>&nbsp;</span><br />
  </td>
  <td width="175" align="center">
    <input class="auto" type="text" id="bwPound" size="18" alt="p8c3pvS" />
  </td>
  <td width="175" align="center">
    <input class="auto" type="text" id="bwPound" size="18" alt="p8c3pvS" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Bob Knothe

Comment: How do you mean refreshed?  Page refresh or do you have a refresh table button?

Comment: Can you add an HTML+CSS snippet as well?

Comment: Could you give the html that is causing the problem?

Comment: When the page is refreshed, does the 6th checkbox keep its state? If not, what state does it get?

Comment: Also, why the unnecessary comparison with `true`?

Comment: And the unnecessary 2nd `if`?

Comment: * Page refresh is browser refresh
* Yes the 6th checkbox keeps the state as checked
* here is the html line for the 
<tr class="hide5">
              <td width="175" align="center" style="padding:1px 0px 11px 0px"><br /><span>Total</span><br /><span>&nbsp;</span><br /></td>
              <td width="175" align="center"><input class="auto" type="text" id="bwPound" size="18" alt="p8c3pvS" /></td>
              <td width="175" align="center"><input class="auto" type="text" id="bwPound" size="18" alt="p8c3pvS" /></td>
            </tr>
Hope this helps

Comment: Would you also add the source for the checkbox to the question? And be sure to indent it at least 4 spaces so it gets formatted as code; you can also use the code button (looks like "101\n010"). It's much more readable that way.

Comment: outis,

Sorry about the mess earlier & thanks for your interest 

Posted just the last check box line - I also tried just an else statement and it did not work.




101\n010 
<td width="90" align="center"><label for="View5">Totals</label><br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="View5" id="View5" value="5" />
                    </td>

Comment: outis,

Here is a link to the whole page

http://www.decorplanit.com/coated_paper_PCBAOW.shtml

Thanks

Comment: @Bob: Note that you can edit your question using the "edit" link just under the tags. Additional, relevant information should go in the question, not the comments.

Comment: @Bob: take a look at petersendidit's answer. It points out a slightly more straightforward implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(rowIndex){
        var $row = $(this);
        if ($row.is(':checked')){
            $('.hide'+rowIndex).show();
        } else {
            $('.hide'+rowIndex).hide();
        }
    });
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {                             
        var row = this.value;
        $('.hide' + row).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox has id "View5", but the JS references `'view'+rowIndex`. [IDs are case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names).